# DDD modify child object through parent

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm writing a monthly expenditure application where you add 'expenditures' to a month, these expenditures contain a description of what the expenditure is and the amount. For example you may have April 2015, and within that you have as expenditure items such as:

- New tires for car $200
- Utility bills $350

etc...

I've written the following, thus allowing you to add items to the month

```
class ExpenditureMonth
{
    public function addExpenditureItem(String description, Money amount)
    {
        items.add(new ExpenditureItem(this, description, amount));
    }
}
```

Therefore the object creation of `ExpenditureItem` happens within `ExpenditureMonth`. An expenditure month can contain many items.

When the account holder has paid for an item, it needs to be marked as paid.

How would I set an item as paid?

My only thinking is set an identifier for an `ExpenditureItem` and pass this instance to the `addExpenditureItem` method but this doesn't seem right to me?!

Comment: Short answer: If you know how to identify an item that needs to be marked as paid, it is enough to git it and mark as paid. The item can have surrogate key if it is needed for your DB. Otherwise it should be implemented as Value Object to identify it somehow.

Comment: Thats the thing, i dont know how to identify the item?! I was thinking of possibly giving the item an id to be able to identify it, but was looking for other suggestions (if any)

Comment: By REST you can identify a resource by IRI, e.g. `/users/123/name`. I guess you can do something similar with your domain object beginning from the actual aggregate root, which I guess already has an id. (But I may not fully understand DDD.)

Comment: When you pass the item to the month, is that the time it gets paid also? or is the item an existing child of the month when it gets paid?

Comment: The item is an existing child. From looking into this over the last few days, ive realised the item needs to be an entity as its something that changes over time, so it'll need an id ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189421/searching-for-a-child-across-aggregate-roots) before (please read the answers).

**In DDD, the parent or the aggregate root changes depending on the bounded context.** So in your case, this is your context:

> When the account holder has paid for an item, it needs to be marked as paid.

For that particular context, the expenditure item is now the aggregate root, and now it requires ID to be identified on its own. Setting up an ID or a GUID is the generally accepted solution, I don't think it is reliable to uniquely identify an object without a proper key.

However, if the case is *"the account holder paid for all his monthly unpaid expenditures (or all unpaid expenditures)"*, then for that context the aggregate root is your MonthlyExpenditure.