# Should entities in a AggregateRoot also become an AggregateRoot

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to setup my domain models around the DDD principles. Right now I have the following class:

```
class Customer : AggregateRoot
{
    public string CustomerReference {get;set;}
    public string CustomerName {get;set;}
    public string List<Adult> Adults {get;set;}
    public string List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
```

Creating a `Customer` is the essence of the application, so I made that class an `AggregateRoot`. Because a lot of 
times the end user will want to find a customer by its `CustomerReference` key.

But then again, sometimes the end user wants to search by the name of a `Child`, to find out the `Customer` info. Or even sometimes
by the name of an `Adult`.

I'm not sure if that means that I should make the `Child` and `Adult` classes also an `AggregateRoot`? Or should I ***always***
start searching from the `Customer` AggregateRoot if I want to search by a `Child` or `Adult` name?

Comment: You shouldn't drive your domain model design based on your Query operations but on your Command ones. It's hard to answer the question without a deeper understanding of the use cases your app has to provide. Can a Customer have more than N childrens? If Children is the AR and you add more without going through the Customer you won't be able to satisfy the "max children added" invariant. That was just a quick example to see how to model your domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for a Child across Aggregate Roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189421/searching-for-a-child-across-aggregate-roots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - aggregate root members are only accessible via the aggregate root.

however, ***If*** you are wanting to manipulate Adult/Child entities on their own, it is likely you don't need the full `Adult` and `Child` entities as part of the customer root. If this is the case replace those collections of entities with collections of Id's and rely on the fully entities to be provided to any functions that require their attributes.

```
class Customer : AggregateRoot
{
    public string CustomerReference {get; private set;}
    public string CustomerName {get; private set;}
    public string IEnrumerable<AdultId> Adults {get; private set;}
    public string IEnrumerable<ChildId> Children {get; private set;}

    public void RegisterAnAdult(Adult adult) {...} 
    public void RegisterAChild(Child child) {...} 
}
```

I emphasised ***If*** because this looks a little bit off unless your system is huge and `Adult` and `Child` can belong to multiple customers. (How do you handle when an child grows up to transition to an adult?)

As @mgonzalezbaile said, don't model your domain based on queries - searching is a whole different thing - model it on business behavior. (For more info start with [http://www.zankavtaskin.com/2016/06/applied-domain-driven-design-ddd-part-7.html])

Finally, in your example the properties are publicly set-able, if this is on purpose then it might be worth stepping back and re-reading the literature on DDD a few more times, public settable properties potentially allow your entity to move to an invalid state, something that DDD tries to avoid.